# How to do expand and collapse AJAX ACCORDION in button_click in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In my ASP.NET web page having Ajax Accordion with two AccordionPane(tab1,tab2).In tab2 contain a button.If i click the button in tab2,then it will expand tab1 and collapse tab2.No Client side  coding.I need to write coding on cs file in button_click

How to do expand and collapse AJAX ACCORDION in button_click ?

Comment: Hello GiRi!  Here on Stack Overflow, you should always show what you've tried so far that isn't working.  Could you show your code, and mention what you don't understand about how it's supposed to work, or where you're running into problems?  See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), especially the "Do your homework" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UserAccordion.SelectedIndex = 1
```